# SQL: Find the names of sailors who have reserved at least two boats

Tags: sql, oracle

### Question

Consider the table:

```
sailors (sid, sname, rating, age)
boats (bid, bname, color)
reserves (sid, bid, date)
```

Find the names of sailors who have reserved at least two boats.

### My Approach

```
select s.sid,count(b.bid) 
from sailors s, reserves r
where s.sid=r.sid 
group by r.sid 
having count(r.bid) > = 2
```

I got the answer in this query.

But the answer gives

```
SELECT sname
FROM s, r r1, r r2
WHERE s.sid=r1.sid 
  AND s.sid=r2.sid 
  AND r1.bid<>r2.bid
```

Both are giving the same answer, but I just want to know the sequence of how it actually works; the associativity.

Please help me out.

Comment: your approach.... where is b alias defined?  so it should be throwing an error. The answer uses a static approach and isn't scalable for 5-6 boats reserved like your apporach is close to.  The answer approach simply does a second join to the reserves table on the sailor ensuring the boats don't match.  The lack of a record in both data sets R1, r2 for the same sailor with different boats would eliminate the sailor that doesn't have at least 2.  I personally find the answer combersome but accurate if you need the data of both boats on the same row; but your answer more maintainable

Comment: The answer example creates two aliases for the table `reserves` (not seen in the query you posted) both joined to sailors.  the where condition filters out rows where the two aliased tables point to the same record (net result, sailors with at least two boats reserved).

Comment: Please clarify your question: what do you mean by: "I just want to know the sequence of how it actually works; the associativity."  is this a question regarding performance? Scaling? the order of operation within the database?  if the latter it varies by database...

Comment: @xQbert sorry sir , i misplaced 'r' with 'b'.Updated now ,thanks

Comment: @xQbert , i want to know the order of operation for the answer qury

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oracle !

Answer (score 2):

your approach isn't that far off but you really should use EXPLICIT join syntax unless the RDBMs doesn't support it but seeing it is more than 20 years old as a standard it should.

```
select
    s.sid, count(DISTINCT r.bid) as NumberOfBoats
from
    sailors s
    INNER JOIN reserves r
    ON s.sid = r.sid 
group by
    s.sid 
having
    count(DISTINCT r.bid) > = 2
```

One issue you have is with your approach is you are counting all reservations of bid NOT unique bids which means if they rented the same boat more than once the record would still be returned.  You want to use DISTINCT r.bid to only find sailors that have rented more than 1 boat.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement literaly responds to question because it summarizes the number of bids for each sailor and then keeps the records that have a count greater or equal to two.

The second statement infers the answer. To do it, it matches all the relations between each sailor and their bids twice, and names each set of relations as if they were two different tables. Finally it keeps those records where the sailor has more than one bid by comparing the bid related to each sailor in one of the *tables* to the same bids relate to the same sailor in the other *table*. To see this more clearly replace `sname` with * in the select and you'll see how fields get repeated.

This statement however will return `n*n-n` results because it is not asking about the number of bids, it is asking where two bids (for the same sailor) are different. So if there are originally 3 different bids (a,b, and c) when doing the matching it will find the same sailor with the following different bids: a <> b, b <> a, a <> c, c <> a, b <> c, and c <> a.
As you see the answer is infered because to have at least one difference means to have at least 2 bids.